# issue when embedding the both Youtube video url and Vimeo video url from json response in angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, video, youtube

```
var app = angular.module('speakout', []).config(
        function($sceDelegateProvider) {
            $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([ 'self',
                    '*://www.youtube.com/**' ]);
            $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([ 'self',
                    '*://player.vimeo.com/video/**']);

        });
```

I am new to angular js. I am trying to append both youtube url and vimeo video url at the same time in my jsp page,but it is working for vimeo and not working for an youtube when i am trying the above code.It is working for individual videos but not both.

anyone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try single call to `resourceUrlWhitelist` with parameters `['self','*://www.youtube.com/**', '*://player.vimeo.com/video/**']`

Comment: Thanka a lot I got it.

Comment: Great! added that as answer.

Comment: Hey, i am new in AngularJs and i face same problem to load and display multiple video Url from https://www.youtube.com/embed/***   video url from json response in angularjs so any body can give me full example. and i want to render video in <iframe ng-src="{{ }}">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most probably would be happening because the second call to

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([ 'self',
                    '*://player.vimeo.com/video/**']);
```

override the first settings.

Try to combine the white list elements.

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([ 'self','*://www.youtube.com/**', '*://player.vimeo.com/video/**']);
```